# Angular 2 router unable to navigate when called from OnInit of component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am building a testportal where students can give test,so on `OnInit` of `TestComponent`.I get the complete test from a service and then route to the questions or the instruction component depending upon the state of test(paused or starting for the first time).

It is not working there,even though the promise returned by `this.router.navigate` is resolving,If I put my `this.router.navigate` code in a `settimeout` ,even with a timeout of 0 it works and navigates properly.

Any help on how to handle this case and details on why it is not navigating properly,I looked at the router's code but could not seem to find anything there.
This is from angular2 final release.

TL;DR
`this.route .navigate` is not working on the `OnInit` of component.

> @angular/router: 3.0.0
>
> @angular/common: 2.0.0

Comment: Why do you want to use router rather than a question component loading the question or an instruction component loading an instruction, based on a ngSwitch?

Comment: Well there are multiple sections and questions.And also a question listing clicking on which the selected question's component is set into the router outlet.So I mange which question to initialize based on the route.I hope this somewhat answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
  RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { initialNavigation: false });
```

My issue was because,I was trying to navigate to a different url,before inital navigation was over.Putting this line in app.routing.ts solved the issue.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11748